# Add html5 placeholders to node_add inputs

Tags: forms

I'd like to add placeholders to node_add field inputs. I'm trying to use dpm($form) but am not sure where to put it. I couldn't get node-add.tpl to work with this

```
 function MYTHEME_theme() {

  $items = array();

  $items['node_add'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'node-add',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
      'MYTHEME_bootstrap_preprocess_node_add'
    ),
  );

  return $items;

}
```

The only template I got to work was page--node--add.tpl but $form shows a blank krumo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add placeholders, or any custom attributes, you need to dig deeper: implement appropriate [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). For node add/edit form, it will be `mymodule_form_node_form_alter`. First parameter is `&$form` - as you can see, it is taken by reference, so changes made to it are carried outside the function. Use `dpm($form)` to find appropriate element. Once you do, use [`#attributes`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes) to add attributes you want.

Comment: Had no idea you could dpm in a custom module. Drupal theming is confusing. Got it working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @delz dpm is a devel function, you can use it almost anywhere. Just remove it after development is finished.

Answer (score 0):

For adding placeholders you could use the #attributes property of the form elements. I'd suggest using a form_alter-hook for that. You can put the code into the template.php of your theme (or into it's own module). It would look something like:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['title']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Title placeholder');
}
```

Comment: As far as I remember (and it seems confirmed in discussion [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1418546)) you are not right - form alter can be used in template.php

Comment: Yes, you are right. It can be verfied by looking at the source of drupal_alter(). alter-hooks are always invoked for the active theme and it's base_themes. [Correcting the answer …]

Comment: Ah it has one caveat: It only works iff the theme has been initialized in the current request. Depending on which hook you are trying to implement it might fail in some cases.